# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.date'

Tags: python, pandas

```
temp = df_cleaned.groupby(by=['CustomerID', 'InvoiceNo'], as_index=False) 
['TotalPrice'].sum() 
  basket_price = temp.rename(columns = {'TotalPrice':'Basket Price'})


# date de la commande
df_cleaned['InvoiceDate_int'] = df_cleaned['InvoiceDate'].astype('int64')
 temp = df_cleaned.groupby(by=['CustomerID', 'InvoiceNo'], as_index=False) 
['InvoiceDate_int'].mean()
df_cleaned.drop('InvoiceDate_int', axis = 1, inplace = True)
basket_price.loc[:, 'InvoiceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['InvoiceDate_int'])
```

## selection des entrées significatives:

```
basket_price = basket_price[basket_price['Basket Price'] > 0]
basket_price.sort_values('CustomerID')[:6]
```

following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe()

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.date'
```

Comment: Please write questions in English, and add more details (e.g. an example dataframe)

Comment: The error is pretty clear to me. You are (directly or indirectly) passing a faulty parameter to `int()`. You should ask yourself why that is the case instead. Also, for a good question, include a [mcve]. Also, take the [tour] and read [ask].